# ifconfig settings doesn't persist when setting up (reverse) tethering

Tags: ubuntu, ifconfig

I made setup where laptop/ubuntu detects phone/android being attached to usb:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-input.rules 

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6863", RUN+="/root/usb.sh", MODE="0666" # samsung
```

Then usb.sh is run. It executes commands for reverse tethering.

```
sudo ifconfig usb0 10.42.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 >>/root/log    2>>/root/log_err
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo iptables -t nat -F                           >>/root/log     2>>/root/log_err
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE >>/root/log      2>>/root/log_err
```

Log shows that operation went fine and usb0 IP being correct:

```
inet addr:10.42.0.1
```

BUT when I check it manually by executing 'ifconfig', it says that IP for usb0 is:

```
inet addr:192.168.x.x
```

WHY is the setting not preserved?

(On raspberry Pi it works correctly. Why not on laptop/Ubuntu? )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but isn't that `ATTRS{idVendor}=="####:####"`  format where ####:#### comes from `$ lsusb`

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too, first.  <br/>

Comment: ..But found out that it didn't work on ubuntu or raspbian. I'm not specialist in defining those udev commands. Latter part of the "####:####" apparently differs between phone models of Samsung.  But original question remains. Why ifconfig settings disappear. Should I create daemon, signal it, and do config from there. Instead of direct shell invocation?

Comment: I used this guide: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=921169 and check that devices table here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: as a quick fix if usb.sh is working. just copy and save the contents into /etc/rc.local  and all should work fine on each boot